# Ubuntu and undefined symbol for SSLv2_method

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, symbols, ubuntu-11.10

Is Canonical renaming symbols in their package version of openssl, and if so for what purpose?  When I compile openssl-1.0.0e.tar.gz (downloaded from openssl.org directly) from scratch I see the necessary symbol, but Python (and I) can't seem to find it in the packaged version.

Read on for more information about how I diagnosed this problem...

I am trying to compile Python 2.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.10, and get the error message above.  The reason I am using this older Python is that I am trying to make my Ubuntu installation 100% compatible with a production system for development purposes.

When performing

```
strace -feopen make -j4 |& grep "libssl"
```

I see that I am using a promising file:

[pid 22614] open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libssl.so", O_RDONLY) = 7

Running nm, this file has no symbols.  However the .a file does have a similar one:

0000000000000030 T SSLv23_method

The package libssl1.0.0-dbg is installed via synaptic, however when I list the installed files for this package all I see is "The list of installed files is only available for installed packages" which is clearly an Ubuntu bug.  So I am not sure how I am supposed to check which symbols are present in the .so.

However, I am suspicious that they have renamed SSLv2_method to SSLv23_method in any case.

How to proceed to figure out the status of Ubuntu's openssl-1.0.0?

Comment: Did you find any workaround to build Python 2.6 on Ubuntu with SSL support?

Comment: Also see [Issue 5453: Compile error in Boost.Asio with OPENSSL_NO_SSL2](http://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5453) on the Boost Bug Trac. Hopefully Boost guarded use of SSLv3 based on `OPENSSL_NO_SSL3`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Ubuntu people build OpenSSL without SSLv2 support because the protocol has [known security issues](https://superuser.com/questions/246074/ssl-whats-the-reason-for-disabling-ssl-v2-support).  So that's why you can't find `SSLv2_method` in their library even though you can find it when you compile the library yourself.

Ubuntu build logs are publicly [available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+builds).  You can see in the [oneiric-i386.openssl_1.0.0e](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/80016018/buildlog_ubuntu-oneiric-i386.openssl_1.0.0e-2ubuntu1_BUILDING.txt.gz) log that the library gets configured with the `-no-ssl2` option, which disables support for SSLv2.

```
./Configure --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=lib/i386-linux-gnu no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 zlib  enable-tlsext no-ssl2 debian-i386
Configuring for debian-i386
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-idea         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_IDEA (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-mdc2         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_MDC2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default] 
    no-ssl2         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
```

Note that the availability of `SSLv23_method` does not mean that a client will be able to connect to a server with SSLv2.  The OpenSSL documentation briefly [discusses this situation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html):

> The list of protocols available can later be limited using the
>   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 options of the
>   SSL_CTX_set_options() or SSL_set_options() functions. **Using these
>   options it is possible to choose e.g. SSLv23_server_method() and be
>   able to negotiate with all possible clients, but to only allow newer
>   protocols like SSLv3 or TLSv1.**

Comment: That hit the spot!  Thanks for answering such a focused question!

Comment: @kirill_igum: ... did you notice the other answer given by Carl Meyer?

Comment: @indiv it looks more like a hack. I was expecting to install some other library from official ppas.  but i guess it the best that is available.

Comment: @kirill_igum:  Oh, I see.  Well, you can always compile OpenSSL yourself with SSLv2 included and install it on your box.  Download OpenSSL source code, `./configure`, `sudo make install`.  I haven't tried this personally but can't think of any problems arising from it (other than re-enabling a deprecated algorithm with known security issues).

Comment: I believe that the latest release of [M2Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto/) (or even couple of releases before) should deal with SSLv2 missing support just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to build Python 2.6 with SSL support on Ubuntu 12.04 with the help of the patch in [this blog post](http://blog.schmichael.com/2012/05/29/building-python-2-6-8-on-ubuntu-12-04/).

Answer (score 0):

My fix was install openssl without ssl2 support

```
./config --prefix=/usr enable-shared -no-ssl2
```

Then install anything linked to the libraries in /usr/ssl. It works..