# Install m2crypto on a virtualenv without system packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, m2crypto

I have created a virtual environment without the system packages with python's virtualenv in Ubuntu and installed m2crypto, but when I execute a shell and I try to import M2Crypto i get the following error:

```
ImportError: /home/imediava/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-          
packages/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

From outside the environment I run into the same problem unless from ubuntu I install python-m2crypto with apt-get. I know that I could create the environment with the system packages but I would prefer not to do it.

Is there anyway that I could create a virtual environment without the system packages and then install m2crypto with pip without running into the SSLv2_method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can install this lib in your global environment and then just copy from your global site-packages to virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have my ubuntu right now but I'll try it later. Is it that simple to do? Don't you think there would be other problems?

Comment: Thanks, it did work! Now I guess is up to the guys either from ubuntu or from m2crypto to figure out why the pypi version doesn't work for ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I copied M2Crypto from ''dist-packages'' successfully, e.g.:

from: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto
to: ~/.virtualenvs/XXX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8219807/1231384.  Also, instead of copying the entire directory, remember you can just symlink: ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto ~/virtualenvs/XXX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto

Answer (score 31):

There seems to be a regression bug from an earlier version of M2Crypto.

After placing [M2Crypto's source](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto#Downloads)  in your virtualenv, you can try to [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) it with the [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) code below.

You do this by downloading the source code, untar it via:
`tar -xzf M2Crypto-0.21.1.tar.gz`

This should create the directory `M2Crypto-0.21.1` which will contain the `SWIG` directory

In `SWIG` you'll find `_ssl.i`, which is the file to be patched. In the same directory create a file called `_ssl.i.patch` for example using the [nano](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) editor and paste the complete diff code listed below into it.

Next issue the `patch _ssl.i _ssl.i.patch` command to merge the patch into the code. (Afterwards you may remove the patch file if you want.)

Finally issue the commands:

`python setup.py build`

followed by:

`python setup.py install`

to install manually.

**diff code:**

```
--- SWIG/_ssl.i 2011-01-15 20:10:06.000000000 +0100
+++ SWIG/_ssl.i 2012-06-17 17:39:05.292769292 +0200
@@ -48,8 +48,10 @@
 %rename(ssl_get_alert_desc_v) SSL_alert_desc_string_long;
 extern const char *SSL_alert_desc_string_long(int);

+#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
 %rename(sslv2_method) SSLv2_method;
 extern SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_method(void);
+#endif
 %rename(sslv3_method) SSLv3_method;
 extern SSL_METHOD *SSLv3_method(void);
 %rename(sslv23_method) SSLv23_method;
```

Comment: There are several M2Crypto forks on Github meanwhile; I added mine to have this excellent patch (https://github.com/tobiasherp/M2Crypto).

Comment: @bosse-klykken Could you please contact me either commenting on https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/commit/b333e591d076154cbf3171b97877d4bd645f64a8 or via email (mcepl at redhat dot com), so that I can acknowledge you as an author of this patch, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

M2Crypto 0.22.3 (the current version in pypi) fixes this problem, so the simplest solution is now simply:

```
pip install --upgrade M2Crypto
```

M2Crypto 0.22.3 has been released from [martinpaljak's github repository](https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto/tree/v0.22.3), rather than from the original [M2Crypto repository](https://github.com/M2Crypto/M2Crypto).

Comment: Easiest solution, should be at the  top

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the current release (M2Crypto-0.22.5).  The latest RC build worked for me.

```
pip install M2Crypto==0.22.6rc4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [patch](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/117) slated for 0.26.1.

In the meantime, you can clone the repo, apply the patch, and install from source.

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto.git
(
    cd m2crypto
    git checkout 0.25.1
    curl 'https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/117.diff' | git apply -v
)
pip install -U m2crypto
```