# pip failing to install any packages - ssl.py error

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, pip

Whenever I try to install any package from pip (Flask, Github-Flask, Django even upgrading setuptools), I always am faced with this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 561, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I am using Kubuntu 12.04, python 2.7. I have already tried reinstalling python2.7 and pip. Any ideas?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/13878827/1265154

Comment: Solution: the ISP I was using was blocking certain types of traffic. I just VPNed into another network and it solved my problem.