# Python pip extremely slow to download (stuck at Colecting...)

Tags: python, pip

I don't know why, it's been some weeks, pip is slow like hell to retrieve a package (like 5 minutes per package).

it hangs at "Collecting [...]"

any idea ?

I tried different versions of pip and of python / pypy, same problem.

There are other questions on that, but there are from 2013/2014 which is pretty old and maybe not applicable (at least, I tried them with no result)

Comment: `pip install -vvv` may print more info to give you some insight.

Comment: using it, it looked like it was stuck on a HTTPS request. So I tried to add a `--timeout 1` and it's much faster now, but I don't know if it is *the* answer

Comment: Can you add the log to the question?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem due to brocken dns-server.

please, try to check your dns-servers (via nslookup utility) and try to fix it (in our case we removed bad dns-servers).

Answer (score -3):

pip repositories can be under heavy load and that may cause slow download ratio.

I would suggest trying to use mirrors.

```
pip install --use-mirrors
```

This flag will automatically use backup mirrors.

Comment: `no such option: --use-mirrors`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403263/canonical-replacement-for-use-mirrors