# how to debug python package after git clone without running the setup.py

Tags: python, git, debugging

I have a git repository I've cloned and I've run the setup.py that installs the package. I have enough experience that I know how to insert ipdb.set_trace() into lines of code where I want to start debugging. I have not yet though understood how to run the cloned code in such a way that it's not being run form the binaries created by the setup.py and as I understand it, then compiled and untouchable.

Can someone illuminate as to how to execute a python package in this way?

Comment: Are you talking about specific package? `setup.py` could trigger C/C++/other code compilation.

Comment: Specifically it's Salt, which is written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Just the general course of actions.

1. I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 and inside virtualenv

   ```
   virtualenv salt-test --system-site-packages
   ```

   We need `--system-site-packages` due to some [bugs after installation of M2Crypto inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547332/install-m2crypto-on-a-virtualenv-without-system-packages)
2. Prerequsites:

   ```
   apt-get install swig libssl-dev
   ```
3. `git clone https://github.com/saltstack/salt.git`
4. `cd salt`
5. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/salt`
7. Now we can run master daemon: `./scripts/salt-master -l debug`

You'll see a lot of output and it would hint you what you need to create to run master properly.

**NB:** After installation I have to activated virtualenv under root to start master

Comment: Is it standard to have a scripts directory containing what gets made into the binaries when setup.py is run?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There are helper scripts/programms inside scripts folder. It may contain just anything. Try opening `scripts/salt-master` with text editor and you'll see python code.

Comment: What I'm asking is can I apply this process to other python programs? Is it standard in python to have a scripts directory containing what becomes the commands one can run after setup.py is executed? I'm trying to understand what places the commands after setup.py is run, and if there's a standard practice in python.

Comment: Well, yes but not to all of them. If python package needs to be build it could be archived by calling `python setup.py build`. On the other hand there might not be `requirements.txt`. Sometimes `setup.py` scripts could rather.. mad at first sight. So basicaly you need just two things: satisfy requirements for you package and build python modules. After that you can add your package to `PYTHONPATH` and use it.