# MDM server - M2Crypto: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method

Tags: python, mdm, m2crypto

I have downloaded a code from [GitHub](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server.git). I tried to run that code in my linux machine and i have installed all required libraries.But the code is not working and displaying the following error. Please help me to get out of this problem.I will be thankful to you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from M2Crypto import SMIME, X509, BIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from M2Crypto import (ASN1, AuthCookie, BIO, BN, DH, DSA, EVP, Engine, Err,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/ASN1.py", line 15, in <module>
    from M2Crypto import BIO, m2, util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/BIO.py", line 10, in <module>
    from M2Crypto import m2, util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/m2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from M2Crypto._m2crypto import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.py", line 26, in <module>
    __m2crypto = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('__m2crypto', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.25.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

Comment: COuld you tell us your OS, version of Python, OpenSSL, and compiler to be used, please?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, python2.7 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: And you are certain that all you did was just ``python setup.py clean build install``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072709/780190) answer suggests a patch for `M2Crypto-0.21.1`, it never worked for me.
By default ubuntu has `openssl` built without `SSLv2` support as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219807/780190), I had to compile `openssl` from source to get it working.