# SSLv2 error with rails 3 on ubuntu 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04, sslv2

I m using ruby 1.9.2. Whenever i run bundle install, i get the following error.

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has  occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! 
/home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':    /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method - /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2- p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
from /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:92:in `<top (required)>'
....
```

The things i tried to solve are

1) steps in answer at [undefined symbol: SSLv2_method when running bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759518/undefined-symbol-sslv2-method-when-running-bundle-install)

2) steps by bob at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/hobousers/80wBJcS0IZk though the system had no **x86_64-linux-gnu** folder

3) steps in this blog http://awolf.ru/rails-on-ubuntu-with-rvm/

i cant understand why one of my machine works fine(upgraded from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04)
while the other gives a problem(freshly installed ubuntu 12.04)

**UPDATE:**

the openssl version used by rvm on the working machine is 0.9.8 while the other one has 1.0.1. Some googling resulted that the 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 doent support the SSLv2 whereas it was supported by 0.9.8.

any fix for the above prob would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Any updates on a solution?

Comment: whenever i tried to install/reinstall the opensll pkg(with versions as parameter) for rvm, it installed the latest(1.0.1) which breaks too. i will update the question n specify a answer whenever i find a solution . hope u find it too.

Answer (score 0):

Some distributions doesn't support SSLv2 due to [security flaws](https://superuser.com/questions/246074/ssl-whats-the-reason-for-disabling-ssl-v2-support). Make sure, you've removed any previous versions of RVM:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/ruby-rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Install RVM:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | 
  bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```