# How do I fix Error loading RubyGems plugin?

Tags: openssl, rubygems, rvm, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

My original purpose was to start a new rails project by getting the most updated versions of rails and ruby. In doing so I broke something.

My question seems to be often repeated in one form or another. I've spent much of the morning going over the solutions from StackOverflow and other web sources, but none have helped me solve my problem.

I have imploded rvm and reinstalled it. I have tried to update to the newest openssl and not seemed to get me no closer to building anything. I've apt-get update, dist-upgrade, upgrade, autoclean and I'm still here typing to ask for help figuring out what I do next to get building.

Here is an error message I get with many rvm and gem terminal commands:

```
ruby 2.3.3-p222
╳  ad_board rvm default                                                                                                                                executive pajamas
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/reed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": /home/reed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: symbol SSLv2_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/reed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/reed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": /home/reed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: symbol SSLv2_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/reed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
```

Depending on the command I use, I also get different info, but this is pretty consistently popping up for most of the rvm and gem commands I use.

What should I be trying to do to fix this problem? What other info do you need from me to aid in finding a solution?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I used the directions from this link to help me: [helpful link](https://29a.ch/2011/10/28/rvm-on-ubuntu-11-10)

What I put in my terminal:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )

source /etc/profile
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall all --force --with-openssl=$rvm_path/usr
```

I got this error message at the end, but otherwise have not had any more issues: `Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): all.`

Comment: Also see [undefined symbol: SSLv2_method when running bundle install](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12759518) and [Building ruby with rbenv and ruby-build fails with undefined symbol: SSLv2_method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36286437).