# undefined symbol: SSLv2_method when trying to run Thin webserver

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've installed OpenSSL with rvm (`rvm pkg install openssl`) and then did `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

When I try to run the thin webserver, I get the following error:

> /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so:
>   undefined symbol: SSLv2_method -
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
>   (LoadError)

This is running on Ubuntu 12.04, and I've read that Ubuntu 12 builds OpenSSL without SSLv2 support. Yet, here it's referencing RVM's package -- does RVM do the same? Is there any known workaround for this problem?

Comment: I've hit exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I think it would be fixed if you could install a particular version of the openssl pkg - I believe 0.9.8 might be what you want.

Comment: Not sure how to do this, but rvm version 1.14.7's openssl package version is 0.9.8t. I'll let you know if it works when i've recompiled ruby.

Comment: did it work for you..? I ended up using CentOS

Comment: Yeah it did! Now I'm going to post an answer and claim some upvotes!

Comment: Hi - it's me from the future. Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, Ubuntu builds openssl without SSLv2 support: [Ubuntu and undefined symbol for SSLv2_method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206546/undefined-symbol-sslv2-method)

For people reading this, your options are (in increasing difficulty):

(1) install rvm version 1.14.7, where the openssl pkg includes openssl version 0.9.8, and includes SSLv2 support by default.

```
rvm implode # Completely destroy your rvm installation
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --version 1.14.7
```

Install the required packages, recompile your ruby, and it should work!

(2) (This gives you more security): Compile your own openssl from source, configuring it to include SSLv2 support, then recompile your ruby with the --with-openssl-dir pointing at wherever you installed openssl to.

(3) Fix thin so that it no longer requires the SSLv2_method symbol, then submit a pull request on [GitHub](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/)

Comment: from the bottom of my cold, developer heart: thank you. I didn't have this exact problem, but your solution #1 was exactly what I needed.